# Can't seem to get line spacing to what I want

Tags: html, css

I've done lots of what seemed more complex stuff and I thought this would be the easy bit but I just don't know where I'm going wrong.

I have a progress bar and want some text above it, very close to the bar itself. If I use just plain text with a  after, the text is where I want it but I would like use css to format these headings. When I do that I can't seem to get the line spacing down enough even if I set line-height very low in css.

```
<h5 id="bar1Title"></h5><h5 id="bar1Title2"></h5>
<progress id="bar1" value="30" max="255"></progress>
```

Also I would like to put bar1Title and bar1Title2 on the same line, another simple task I don't seem able to do!

Comment: try using < span > or another similar tag rather than h1-5

Comment: I would wrap them in a <SPAN> or <DIV> tag then style them

Comment: are you putting the text in <h5> tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**h5** is a `block level element` .. So you need to explicitly set the display: inline for these elements if you want them to appear side by side.

```
h5
{
    display : inline;
}
```

Also you can tweak the margin property and set it to negative if the line height does not work..

Comment: display:inline worked perfectly and solved both issues. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
<h5 id="bar1Title" style="margin-bottom:-2px;"></h5><h5 id="bar1Title2" style="margin-bottom:-2px;"></h5>
<progress id="bar1" value="30" max="255"></progress>
```

try using style="margin-bottom:-2px;" and increase the value of px as you want so that it will go down the line

Answer (score 0):

will this do?

```
<div>
    <span id="bar1Title">111</span>
    <span id="bar1Title2">222</span>
</div>
<div style="line-height: 0px;margin-top: -3px;">
    <progress id="bar1" value="30" max="255"></progress>
</div>
```

or this

```
<h5 id="bar1Title" style="display: inline">111</h5>
<h5 id="bar1Title2" style="display: inline">222</h5>
<div style="line-height: 0px;margin-top: -3px;">
    <progress id="bar1" value="30" max="255"></progress>
</div>
```

Comment: Clear the closing </h5> tag : )

Answer (score 0):

Heading tags have some default margins that you need to consider.

http://www.htmlcssdeveloper.com/tutorial/advanced-html-css/what-is-the-default-margin-of-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-h6.html

You have to clear that margin

```
<h5 style="margin: 0px;"></h5>
```